# how to print the value of variable in jquery for loop

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    var totrows= $('#table').attr('rows').length;
    for(i=0; i < totrows; i++){
      //var rowid = $('#table').$(this).attr('i'); 
      alert(rowid);
    }
  });
});
```

In The  above function when we click on hyperlink "Show" we are getting the number of rows from the "table1".I want to add the Value of 'i' to the table so that it becomes "table1""table2""table3""table4""table5".The commented line is giving me error

Comment: Can you post the HTML you have...and what you want the result to be?  It would make the question/intent *much* clearer.

Comment: I Want to append the value of 'i' in the forloop to the 'table'

Comment: @Someone - Just the variable, or you want to stick text into the table, e.g. creating elements?

Comment: @nick -I want to stick the value

Comment: @nick i want to append the value of variable 'i' to the table .So that it becomes 'table1', 'table2'

Comment: @Someone - You're being very unclear here...can you post the HTML and expected result?  If you just want a string, it's simply `var rowid = "table" + i;` but I'm not sure that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Following is your actual code which is buggy, I'll try to explain the odds in your program, which may help you in future coding.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    var totrows= $('#table').attr('rows').length;
    for(i=0; i < totrows; i++){
      //var rowid = $('#table').$(this).attr('i'); 
      alert(rowid);
    }
  });
});
```

The Above Code isn't written in right way, because

**1**) `var totrows= $('#table').attr('rows').length;`

is there any attribute(or specified) by name '**rows**' in your **table** element ?? and why do u bother about the length of an attribue ?

**2**) second thing, when you are using `this` make sure which element it is going to refer. In your code,

```
   $('#show').click(function(){
      var totrows= $('#table').attr('rows').length;
       for(i=0; i < totrows; i++){
          //var rowid = $('#table').$(this).attr('i'); 
           alert(rowid);
        }
   });

    
//var rowid = $('#table').$(this).attr('i');
```

The above line(commented) is Invalid, it should be some thing like  `$(this).attr('myAttr');` and moreover it is referring to  `$('#show')` ( `this` should refer to `tr` elements if you're going to do some stuff with `tr` elements

**3**)

```
for(i=0; i < totrows; i++){
      //var rowid = $('#table').$(this).attr('i'); 
      alert(rowid);
    }
```

In the **for** loop `i` is a counter variable and not an **attribute**

**4**) Last thing make good use of jQuery **[API](http://api.jquery.com/)** , **[jQuery.com](http://jquery.com)** is providing it for free :)

**edit** :
if you want me to code for you, I would do something as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show').click(function() {
      $('#table tr').each(function(i) {
         alert('table' + (i+1));
      });
    });
});
```

In `.each()` function we pass an **Index** and an **Element** as parameters like

`$(selector).each(function(Index,Element){    //do some thing   });`

By default the `Index` is initialized  with `0`, so if you want get your final outcome as {`table1,table2...`} just append the value of `Index` after incrementing it by `1`

for more Info refer to [jquery](http://jquery.com) website for [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) as `nick` said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the overall intent, but it would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    var totrows= $('#table').attr('rows').length;
    for(i=0; i < totrows; i++){
      var rowid = 'table' + (i+1); 
      alert(rowid);
    }
  });
});
```

This would alert "table1", "table2", etc...one for every length of `.rows`  `i` starts at `0` so you need to add `1` to it.  If you want it based on the number of `<tr>` elements instead of some attribute, you could use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/),  like this:

```
$(function(){ //short for $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').click(function(){
    $('#table tr').each(function(i) {
      var rowid = 'table' + (i+1); 
      alert(rowid);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to insert index into each row or something like this e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){

    $('#mytable').find("td").each(function(i,el){

      $(el).text($(el).text()+i)

    });
  });
});​
```

It works on following html

```
 <input type="button" id="show" value="Show">

 <table id="mytable">
   <tr><td>row</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row</td></tr>
 </table>
```

You can try this out here http://jsbin.com/apeto3

Comment: Have you seen the output of your code when you click `show` button more than **once**, the output which I got after clicking twice is the `Index' is appending to the previous text. checkout !!!

Comment: @Samurai Jack , yes that is what it was made to do, demonstrating how text can be modified on fly, as i am not exactly clear what OP wants